# How to stop animation for an activity

Tags: android

I have an activity that appears as a dialog using the following custom theme:

```
<style name="ThemeDialogNoAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowFrame">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Notice I have no animations set, yet when the activity exists is still slides to the right. How do I stop it from animating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The animations you're seeing most likely come from the system but they're easy to override.

If you want no transition when the activity starts:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

If you want no transitions when the activity finishes:

```
@Override
public void finish() {
    super.finish();

    overridePendingTransition(0, 0);
}
```

Passing in 0 when overriding transitions signals to the system to use no transitions.  In place of 0 you could also add in a custom transition of your own by passing in the resource identifier to an animation resource.

Comment: Actually this almost works. I'm starting activity B in the onResume() of activity A. Since activity B is not full screen you can see activity A under it and this technique also affects the transition of activity A on entering. I only want to affect the transition of activity B, the overlaying activity.

Comment: overridePendingTransition takes in an identifier for an animation resource. The first is the enter transition, the second is the exit.  If you don't want any transitions for B only, then specify 0 for the enter transition in onCreate and 0 for the exit transition in finish for Activity B. Unfortunately, you can't tell the system to use the default for the other activity. You're always going to affect the other activity by overriding.

Android OEMs will tweak the default transition but the typical defaults are android.R.anim.fade_in and android.R.anim.fade_out if you want to put those in.

Comment: Thanks MCeley. That works for no animation on the second activity (B) which is what I originally asked about so you are correct. Odd thing is, if I try to set an enter animation for activity B activity A gets the same animation. So if I set B to zoom in then both A and B zoom in at the same time. Strange.

Comment: That is rather strange. If you could post a code snippet I might be able to help figure it out.